# how to create an import page to import contacts from an e-mail address using php?

Tags: php, email, import

I have a question about importing contacts using PHP

I have a registration form that the user needs to submit his email and i redirect him to an import.php
what i need now is to import his contact list from his email account after he puts in his password for this account.

and try and send them invitation email.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/). It's a free and open-source solution.